# Alter sessionState SQLServer schema

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

In a large scale application we are using SQL Server as session state; so we have built `ASPState` database with the following tables:

- ASPStateTempSessions
- ASPStateTempApplications

I have requirements to add some additional informations (eg. installation code, user code, and so on) to `ASPStateTempSessions` table and update them accordingly so an external service can check it.

I have altered the table schema and is working well but, my question is:

> Is a good practice? Do I have any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> update them accordingly so an external service can check it.

You run the risk of the external service blocking access to the sessions table and thus impairing the site. Make sure the external service uses optimal access to the tables (ie. all queries issued by the service always use an index and do not do table scans) and consider enabling [read committed snapshot](http://blog.codinghorror.com/deadlocked/).